# Previous record, Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I`m trying to get previous record for certain conditions. For example, I want to get like this

```
id | v
__  __
1   50
1   49
0   0
0   0
```

for id 0 I want to get v 49 (previous value for id 1). Рow is this possible to do for all id = 0?

Comment: Why is previous of id=0 49 and not 50?  What is the previous for the last id=0?  Is previous id-1 or the is this `order by id desc, v desc`?

Comment: No, it`s for example. without sort. I want to get previous values, if it != 0/

Comment: this does not help us at all. the problem is in what condition so call  `previous` cause id clearly can't fulfill this purpose (which if a column name id it should).

Comment: for `v` 0 i want to get previouus not `0` value for all id

Comment: "for `v` 0 i want to get previouus not `0` value for all id" . NO there is nothing indicate previous value.

Comment: @roman_ . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You are using the word "previous", but it has no definition unless a column specifies the ordering.  There is no obvious ordering in your question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row unless a column specifies the ordering.  And there is no obvious ordering in your table.

That said, you seem to want the minimum value for `id = 1`.  You can get this using window functions with `filter`:

```
select t.*,
       min(value) filter (where id = 1) over () as imputed_value
from t;
```

If you only wanted two columns, you could use:

```
select t.id,
       (case when id = 0
             then min(value) filter (where id = 1) over () 
             else value
        end) as value
from t;
```